# Every finite division ring has order $|Z|^n$ for some $n\in\Bbb N$ and where $Z$ is the center.

Tags: abstract-algebra, field-theory, finite-fields

I'm reading the proof of Ernst Witt that shows that every finite division ring is a field.

The proof begins with a statement that I don't fully understand:

> Every finite division ring $R$ has order $|Z|^n$ for some $n\in\Bbb N$ and where $Z$ is the center of $R$.

So I guess that this can be shown by showing that $R$ can be written as a $n$ dimensional vector space over $Z$. Because such a vector space would have $|Z|^n$ elements.

I'm not sure how I can see that $R$ is such a vector space over $Z$. How can I show that?

Comment: Presumably the task is to show that every *finite* division ring is a field. Or, that the division ring has finite dimension over a finite field (implying the former). Anyway, can you prove that 1) $Z$ is a field. 2) left multiplication by elements of $Z$ gives $R$ the structure of a vector space over $Z$?

Comment: Yes, you are right. It meant finite division ring. I can show that $Z$ is a field. I'm a bit confused about your second remark. So I need to show that left multiplication by elements of Z gives $R$ the structure of a vector space. And therefore must have $|Z|^n$ elements?

Comment: Correct. That will do.

Answer (score 3):

If $Z$ is a field, then the division ring is a $Z$ vector space of dimension $n$ this implies that its cardinal is $|Z|^n$. Take a basis of the division ring to realize a bijection between $Z^n$ and the division ring.

Comment: If you say, "take a basis of the division ring", don't you then already assume that the ring is a vector space? Or how can I show that I can find such a basis?

Comment: Yes, $R$ is a $Z$-vector space, it is a commutative group and  for every $z\in Z,r,r'\in R$ you can define $z.(r+r')=zr+zr'$ which defines a structure of a $Z$-vector space on $R$.